# How to monitor Azure Virtual Machines running linux?

Tags: azure, network-monitoring

I want to know if there is any azure service or way to monitor Azure Classic Virtual Machines, to see if they are up and running or they are not functioning. Also, It would be beneficial if the service could restart the VM in cases when its not functioning. Is there an inherent way to do this in azure? Also, any other suggestions as to how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

check out Microsoft Operations Management Suite
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/server-cloud/operations-management-suite/overview.aspx

you can access it by creating an Operational Insights workspace from either the classic or ARM portal. there is a free tier, it can help you monitor both Classic and ARM VM's as well as on site resources, O365 and coming soon AWS resources too. it does have some interaction with Azure automation but I think it is just for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers something called "Azure Diagnostics for Virtual Machines"  that you can enable on each VM. It's occasionally also referred to as "Azure VM Diagnostics". These will then in turn allow you to programmatically collect details on resource utilization on a per VM basis. These are supported both in Classic and in ARM.

Docs on how to enable Azure's VM Diagnostics are available at:
- [Configuring Diagnostics for Azure Cloud Services and Virtual Machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-diagnostics-for-cloud-services-and-virtual-machines/)

As an aside Datadog has a [detailed guide](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-microsoft-azure-vms/) explaining the available metrics, how they interact, and [how to collect them](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-azure-metrics/).